# Missing read permission for Zip files created with .net core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, permissions, zip

DotNetZip creates zip files with permission 000 (no read, no write, no execute) and thus I cannot easily open them on Linux (Windows Explorer doesn't care about it and opens the file normally). Same code on Windows produces files with read permission (on Linux):

```
using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream("./test.zip"))
{
  using (var archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
  {
    var entry = archive.CreateEntry("test.txt");
    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(entry.Open()))
    {
      writer.Write("Hello World");
    }
  }
}
```

Can I either set the permissions or emulating that `System.IO.Compression` is running on Windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DotNetZip: creating zip with C# permissions issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606908/dotnetzip-creating-zip-with-c-sharp-permissions-issue)

Comment: Try using this to change the file permissions after the file is created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132081/file-permissions-on-linux-unix-with-net-core

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.net core now exposes the `ExternalAttributes` property of `ZipArchiveEntry` that allows you to set permissions, like this (664):

```
entry.ExternalAttributes = entry.ExternalAttributes | (Convert.ToInt32("664", 8) << 16);
```

note that the string is an octal representation of the permission bit mask, therefore the convert to base 8.